# Shibboleth authenticated user attributes are missing from $_SERVER array of PHP on IIS Window 10 (V10.0.14393.0)

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, shibboleth

I am working on php codeigniter base web application and implementing Shibboleth by installing the **shibboleth-sp-2.6.0.1-win64.msi** on **window 10** with **IIS V10.0.14393.0** on my personal machine.

**ISAPI module** is installed on IIS which is point the module in shibboleth installation **C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\lib64\shibboleth\isapi_shib.dll**

The authentication process working fine and the IdP redirects back to the SP. The Shibboleth session looks **OK, But** the env variables are missing from $_SERVER and the existing one are empty.

I need shibboleth session variables related to authenticated user and want to save it in php session as per my application requirement. I cannot figure out how to do it in PHP on IIS.

**After redirecting back form idp the the /Shibboleth/Session printout the following response data.**

```
Miscellaneous
Session Expiration (barring inactivity): 480 minute(s)
Client Address: 127.0.0.1
SSO Protocol: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol
Identity Provider: http://sts.platform.rmunify.com/sts
Authentication Time: 2017-06-02T07:01:45.867Z
Authentication Context Class: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
Authentication Context Decl: (none)

Attributes
identityguid: c3ec37e9-ff24-4143-be53-9526650cef34
organisationCode: 0020051
organisationid: 9b975206-da98-4893-a47c-e3e68b100169
```

**And the shibd.log file have the following line**

```
2017-06-02 15:52:33 INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [2]: new session created: 
ID (_3dc0307b7f78094057945aa4254b0e15) 
IdP (http://sts.platform.rmunify.com/sts) Protocol(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) 
Address (127.0.0.1)
```

But the `Shib-Session-ID` and some other attributes are missing from $_SERVER array, 
Only get shibboleth attribute `HTTP_SHIBSPOOFCHECK` with other server related data in $_SERVER array and get the following shibboleth cookie `_shibsession_64656661756c74687474703a2f2f6465762e676f6f73656265727279706c61792e636f6d2f73686962626f6c657468`.

> I want the authenticated user data in $_SERVER array, i am unable
>   to figure out why IIS does not mapping the attributes in $_SERVER
>   array.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated, Thanks.